# DELETE from OPENQUERY alias not working

Tags: linked-server, delete

I'm trying to use the following code to execute a `DELETE` statement on a linked server. I'm trying to delete all records from the remote server where there is a match on a certain ID field in both the table on the linked server and a local table. Any records showing up in the `INNER JOIN` should be deleted from the linked server table `RemoteTable`.

The following isn't allowing me to use an alias ("RemoteTable") for my remote table. Am I on the right track here with what I'm trying to accomplish? Thanks!

`DELETE FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER_MYSQL,'SELECT * from PrimaryInquiry_T2') AS RemoteTable
INNER JOIN Forms.dbo.PrimaryInquiry_TLOCAL AS LocalTable
ON LocalTable.PrimaryInquiry_TLOCAL_EntryID = RemoteTable.PrimaryInquiry_T2_EntryID`

Comment: Did you try `DELETE RemoteTable FROM OPENQUERY(...) AS RemoteTable ...`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand That did it! Thanks so much! So I'm assuming this is the best way to accomplish a DELETE on a linked server with a local table as criteria?

Comment: Sure, there are other forms (like EXISTS) but this should do just fine.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Awesome. I was just concerned with making sure I'm using the most efficient method but sounds like it's pretty much 6 to one half dozen to the other in this case. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use SQL Server's proprietary and admittedly awkward self-reference form of delete:

```
DELETE RemoteTable
  FROM OPENQUERY(...) AS RemoteTable ...
```